# Objective C - Lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, lvalue

I get the error (Lvalue required as left operand of assignment) for this code:

```
[[addAlertViewController alertsArray] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil] retain];
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate Code is as follows:

```
[addAlertViewController setAlertsArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil]];
```

Be careful that you have declared in your `@interface` of `addAlertViewController`'s Class:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *alertsArray;
```

And in your implementation file

```
@synthesize alertsArray;
```

[And.. I'll agree with @taskinoor, RTFM.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)

Answer (score 1):

Knowing what an lvalue and rvalue will help when deciphering compiler warnings. A lvalue is something that will be assigned and a rvalue is something that can do the assigning. [More info on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science))

An rvalue can also be a lvalue, like in the case of a = b = c (where c is an rvalue to lvalue b, but then b is a rvalue to the lvalue a).

anytime you see "lvalue required" then look on the left of the = operator, there is an error there.